# Salvar ArrayIterator no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo

Estou tendo dificuldade em salvar uma lista de itens em `ArrayInterator`, onde preciso salvar estes dados na tabela ao clicar em um botão salvar.

Código do array:

```
<?php
    ...
    $p = new ArrayIterator($_SESSION['PEDIDO']);

    while ($p->valid()):

         //$p->key(); Utilizado para pegar os ids.
         //$p->current(); Pega a quantidade de produtos por ids.

         $c = new Carrinho;
         $c->setId($p->key());
         $pedido = $c->listarPedidos();
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $p->key(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pedido->NMPRODRUTO; ?></td>
        <td>R$ <?php echo number_format($pedido->VLVENDA,2,",","."); ?></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="qtde" value="<?php echo $p->current(); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $p->key(); ?>" data-preco="<?php echo $pedido->VLVENDA; ?>"/></td>
        <td align="center" id="subtotal">R$ <?php echo number_format(($pedido->VLVENDA*$p->current()),2,",",".") ?></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="?delete=ok&id=<?php echo $p->key(); ?>"><img src="img/deletar.png" id="excluir" /></a></td>
    </tr>

<?php
   $p->next();
endwhile;?>
```

Comment: seu código não faz menção de salvar dados no banco, você pode incluir a parte do código em que você tenta gravar esses dados? Pode ser que a função [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php) resolva o problema.

Comment: Na verdade eu não o fiz ainda, pois não estou sabendo o que fazer... preciso justamente de como fazer. pode me ajuda @Sanção

Comment: você está tentando salvar no banco de dados o pedido que está na sessão? se sim, salvar o `ArrayIterator` não é a melhor maneira de fazer.

Comment: Tipo, porque isto irá funcionar como um carrinho de compra, onde eu vou efetuo a compra do itens determinado, logo apos entro dentro da pagina carrinho, e clico em efetuar compra. Este paço de efetuar compra que eu quero, porem não estou fazendo loja virtual, mais segue esta ideia.